# How do you communicate from the browser with the express.js server using angular ssr?

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I've run into an SSR issue that somehow neither the Angular docs nor the new Angular dev docs provide information about it or at least I did not find any.

I'd like to know how one transfers data from the browser to the server as the other way around is pretty easy using the TransferState API. It also seems kind of odd to me, that there isn't a TransferState analog for the other way or that the TransferState API isn't bidirectional.

I've tryed adding a post route in the `server.ts` in the `app()` function file like this:

```
server.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('The Body of the Request: ', req.body)
    res.send("Got the request!")
})
```

But whenever I try to call the route like this in the browser:

```
readonly #http = inject(HttpClient)

testEndpoint() {
    this.#http.post('http://localhost:4200/test', {hello: 'world'}).subscribe(console.log)
}
```

But when I try to call this in the browser like this:

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformID)) {
    this.#service.testEndpoint()
}
```

It returns an "NG04002" which basically means that the route couldn't be found by the RouterModule/Router.
This doesn't make sense to me, but maybe I am missing something obvious.

Also do note that the code I provided is only pseudocode and may not be valid javascript/typescript code as I currently do not have access to my real code base. If this isn't suffient enought to pinpoint the error, please tell me, I'll add all of the stuff that is needed as long as this gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

SSR is meant for `prerendering` the content on the server and hydrating (or not) on the client, it is not a web server for writing `node.js` code.

Because whatever routes you will hit, angular will search for the corresponding angular routing for that route!

Instead run a separate `node.js` server in port `4000` or anything except `4200` (default angular server port) and make api calls through this separate server!

Comment: Yes I know that, that is it designed purpose I also intend to use it as such. The problem is, that I need this communication because of something I receive in browser on the front end that I need on the server so that the server optimizes the prerendering. The approach of creating an endpoint was just a try to achieve this but as you said the angular router takes over the whole angular routing. Is this what I'm trying not possible with just angular or can you bypass the angular router somehow? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @SeamonDev as far as I know no, but you should wait for someone more experienced to comment!

Comment: Well thanks anyway. It may very well be that this just isn't meant to work with angular

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. Angular 17 apparently ignores the server.ts file when running ng serve and only take into account when you are building with ng build and executing the .mjs file afterwards. This is because angular uses an internal dev server and not the one you provided in server.ts.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26472
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26323

These github issues were also made by confused people like me, but from what I got this is defined behavior.
As far as I know this isn't documented anywhere inside the official angular documentation.